# Show all burndown projects with the tuleap API

Tags: rest, api, alm, tuleap, burndowncharts

**English :**

Hello everybody !

Do you know if it is possible to recover from the API of the project planning and management tool "Tuleap" the burndown urls of all the projects to which the original user of the request has access?

After several searches in the documentation of the tool and on the internet, I still can not find an answer.

Thank you for the help you can give me! :)

---

**Français :**

Bonjour tout le monde !

Savez-vous s'il est possible de récupérer à partir de l'API de l'outil de planification et gestion de projet "Tuleap" les urls des burndown de l'intégralité des projets auxquels à accès l'utilisateur originaire de la requête ?

Après plusieurs recherche dans la documentation de l'outil et sur internet, je n'arrive toujours pas à trouver de réponse.

Merci pour l'aide que vous pourrez m'apporter ! :)

Comment: Please post if you've found or created an answer to this very cool question.